# Emacs M-x binding on Mac M1

Tags: m-x, mac

In emacs `M-x command-name` can be used to invoke a command.

However in Mac M1, for some reason, this is not working.

Basically, I am trying `option` + `x` or `M-x`.

Any idea about this?

Comment: Are you using Emacs in Terminal.app, or as a separate GUI application? Terminal.app needs to be told to "use option as meta" in the profile section of its settings.

Comment: Thanks that worked